# How to fix/give fix value to the width and height of jquery lightbox?

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox

I have aplied jquery lighbox on my image gallery, but due to the variable size of images, the lightbox size is not fixed hence opens up with image's original size, this in turn causes the biga images to go out of screen and display horizontal scroll bar in browser.

Hence I am looking for the way to apply the fix width and height to lightbox so that every image must be displayed with this size in lightbox.

Please help..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@OM The Eternity: I can't see a way around not messing around with the plugin's source code and found a page with some helpful comments on how to do just that -- http://geekswithblogs.net/wojan/archive/2009/06/17/jquerylightbox.aspx -- though if you'd rather avoid that, you could try out a similar plugin that supports setting a maximum width/height: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: My favorite is fancybox which also allows you to specify a width and height: http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: I Suppose editing the source code will help me as I can see it has helped many of me types :-), Thanks Any Wyas.. U resolved my issue

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Views to display your Lightbox image, the window size is governed and defined by the "Lightbox: Lightbox trigger" Field.